# Allowing non-latin characters in registration

Tags: filters, encoding

I am from Turkey and we have "şŞçÇğĞüÜöÖıİ" characters in our alphabet.

I want to use those characters in permalinks/slugs/usernames. I found temporary solution for permalinks/slugs with core-hacking. There is no other option for it except core-hacking seems. You can find solution here:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15248

My problem is, user registration need a little fix after this one too. Fortunately there is filter i can use but couldnt handle it:

in wordpress includes/formatting.php :

```
function sanitize_user( $username, $strict = false ) {
 $raw_username = $username;
 $username = wp_strip_all_tags( $username );
 $username = remove_accents( $username );
 // Kill octets
 $username = preg_replace( '|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '', $username );
 $username = preg_replace( '/&.+?;/', '', $username ); // Kill entities

 // If strict, reduce to ASCII for max portability.
 if ( $strict )
  $username = preg_replace( '|[^a-z0-9 _.\-@]|i', '', $username );

 $username = trim( $username );
 // Consolidate contiguous whitespace
 $username = preg_replace( '|\s+|', ' ', $username );

 return apply_filters( 'sanitize_user', $username, $raw_username, $strict );
}
```

This section of code is producing error:

```
 if ( $strict )
  $username = preg_replace( '|[^a-z0-9 _.\-@]|i', '', $username );
```

Somehow i need to disable this section. But i am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Mighty good question, This problem is not only in Turkey. It is basically in every European language which is not English. Come to think about it - the problem exists for every language in the world that is not English ! ( Chinese, Japanese, Korean, Arab, Hebrew , Hindu ... basically 2/4 of the world population ... )

Comment: @krembo99 I created plugin for this purpose: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-turkce/ You can inspect and modify it for your language too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (not tested, I hope I am not short circuiting it into endless loop):

```
add_filter('sanitize_user', 'non_strict_login', 10, 3);

function non_strict_login( $username, $raw_username, $strict ) {

    if( !$strict )
        return $username;

    return sanitize_user(stripslashes($raw_username), false);
}
```

Comment: after long long searches, seems its not something supported in php community yet.. unicode permalinks basically what i want seems..  I have an ideas page about it: http://wordpress.org/extend/ideas/topic/non-latin-characters-need-love